# What is "d---d" in "I’m d—d if I don’t ﬁll you"

Tags: meaning-in-context

There is "I’m d—d if I don’t fill you" in Jim Baker's Blue-Jay Yarn by Mark Twain. Does "d---d" used for "doomed" or what could the author meant here?

> ‘Well, you’re a long hole, and a deep hole, and a mighty singular hole altogether—but I’ve started in to ﬁll you, and I’m d—d if I don’t ﬁll you, if it takes a hundred years!’

Comment: Maybe "damned"?

Comment: Twain dashed out the middle letters of 'damned', but left a certain other word whole, in one of the great anti-racist American novels of the 19th century (not that there were very many). Tempus fugit.

Comment: He wrote a [jolly little piece](http://www.textfiles.com/etext/AUTHORS/TWAIN/onanism.txt) about masturbation. As you may gather, I like Mark Twain/Samuel Clemens.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That’s the first time I’ve seen *onanism* used in English. I probably wouldn’t have known what it meant if I didn’t speak Spanish. Interesting.

Comment: Did I mean tempus fugit, or O tempora, O mores! ....?

Comment: 'Onanism' was fairly common up to maybe 1950 or so among scholarly types. The usage, not the practice, I mean. Not that I have any data. More euphemistic that m---------n. Strictly speaking, what Onan did to annoy God (or 'G-d' if we're dashing things) was not the "solitary vice" but rather coitus interruptus. [Onan (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onan)

Comment: As late as 1963, many radio stations only played a censored version of Greenback Dollar by the Kingston Trio, with a guitar strum replacing the word "damn" in the lyrics "I don't give a damn about a greenback dollar".

Comment: Well, I'll be dashed!

Answer (score 18):

It is a way or writing "damned"  In books of this period, swear words and profane  uses of the word "God" were frequently obscured by removing all the middle letters and replacing them with dashes.  So you will see "Oh my G—d"

"I'm damned if I don't fill you" is a way of expressing emphatically (and profanely) the speaker's determination. Literally, the speaker is saying "If I don't fill the hole, then please send me to Hell."  This is hyperbolic speech, and in the standards of the time, it was considered unacceptable to print such a thing.

Comment: A more modern usage of this expression (in my experience, AmE, maybe it's different elsewhere?) would be "I'll be damned". I've heard that version plenty of times.

Answer (score 4):

I [answered this same question on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/477818/191178), and I think the answer is applicable here too (semi-paraphrased).

---

The word here is “damned”. The OED, in an entry that seems to have been written in 1894 and not been updated since then, noted this about the word:

> Now usually printed ‘d——d’.

This was a pretty common way for vulgar words to be censored in the 1800s. You will also see, for example, “b——y” (bloody) and [p—ck](https://books.google.com/books?id=zLAJs0_prpwC&dq=dictionary%20of%20the%20vulgar%20tongue&pg=PP37#v=onepage&q&f=false) (prick) in books of this period.

Note that this is no longer common. First of all, *damned* isn’t considered too bad of a word anymore (not too polite but not so offensive that you need to protect people from seeing it), and words that *are* that offensive have asterisks used instead of dashes.

Comment: Brendan Behan  employed dashes in _Borstal Boy_ (1958), but he dashed out offensive words (or parts of words) entirely, which led to him being called "a dirty little ----er" by a prison guard, and a fellow prisoner saying "---- 'em all".